# Can I Extend activity inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest

I am new on android and I want to follow this guide:
[facebook style newsfeed](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)

But that guide use pure/ordinary activity (mainactivity) not fragment (i am using fragment for left menu drawer page). here is my code:

```
package com.infotech.hotbods;
import com.infotech.hotbods.app.AppController;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.infotech.hotbods.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import com.infotech.hotbods.data.FeedItem;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = PhotosFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";
    public PhotosFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

}

Can I use code like this to make it show inside fragment?

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
    public class FeedPageActivity extends Activity {
        private final String TAG = FeedPageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private ListView listView;
        private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
        private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
        private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";
        //follow the code from guide
    }
}
```

How to make it show inside fragment? (not from initial launch set from android manifest)

Regards.

Comment: It's impossible to show an Activity inside a Fragment. You should port the code from Activity to Fragment by overriding similar method in Fragment like onCreate, onResume and so on.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? From the documentation: "A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. If you embed an activity into a Fragment, the Fragment would need to be responsible for that Activity's life-cycle. That's not how it works. " Please take a look at "Creating a Fragment" in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

No, You are defeating the use of Fragments. Fragments depends on the life-cycle of Activity. Activity is the one who is responsible of holding them, replacing them together. And also the best practice to communicate between the Fragements is also through an Activity. So, Basically the answer is No,